# vba adding brackets to formula when added to cell

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use vba to add a formula to a cell using the below vba

`formula2 = "=IF(MATCH(RC[-8],'Eligible Customers'!K:K,0),""Eligible"","""")"`

but when the macro is run, it pastes

```
=IF(MATCH(C2,'Eligible Customers'!K:(K),0),"Eligible","")
```

the "K:K" bit isn't working as expected and returns the `#NAME?` in the cell, causing everything to break.

Please can anyone help, this is driving me mad...

Comment: you are mixing `R1C1` and `A1` notation.  choose one and use through out the formula string.

Comment: `formula2 = "=IF(MATCH(RC[-8],'Eligible Customers'!C11,0),""Eligible"","""")"`

Comment: @ScottCraner - worked a treat. Thanks so much!